# How to make sure that an NSWindow is repainted at the end of a code block

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

I am updating a window inside a critical section. Because the data that is being painted inside this window is accessed by some one else (inside another critical section), I want to make sure that the window that is painted is updated by the time I exit the critical section.

In Windows, I could use `InvalidateRect` followed by an `UpdateWindow` to ensure that there is force paint and the message is executed instead of simply being pushed into a queue, marked for execution later.

What is the corresponding way to achieve the same effect in OSX?

From the documentation, it appears that something like:

`[myWindow display]` where `myWindow` is of type `NSWindow` should do the trick but it doesn't paint it immediately.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So you run the critical section inside a thread?

Answer (score 2):

You could force it by calling [self setNeedsDisplay] on the view contained within the window, then run a small run loop for a short amount of time to allow the draw messages to propagate through to the display logic.

```
    [viewToRefresh setNeedsDisplay];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode 
                             beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]];
```

This might work. Its a rather odd scenario! YMMV.

Comment: I have tried this but I am a little skeptical about messing with the run loop. Any references that might confirm that doing something like this is safe?

Comment: We've been using this for very different scenarios in code to allow notifications to pump through. it's not an idea situation (and usually I'd rather refactor the code to remove the dependency) but basically the Cocoa  draw loop is out of your control.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you do never draw into a window. You draw into views. A window is simply a container for views.

Second a view should know itself, when and where it needs repainting. If the underneath data is changed, you report that, but not the drawing request. This is because a controller cannot no, which area of the view is affected.

However, after all I assume that the window update request is sent from another thread.

Using GCD it looks like this:

```
// Critical section ends here
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
^{ 
  [affectedView setNeedsDisplay]; 
});
```

Using threads

```
// Critical section ends here
[view performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector( setNeedsDisplay ) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```